If there are cubic polynomial features, then isn't this a polynomial regression, not a linear regression?
I have the following problem:

Consider a Linear Regression problem with two features. Based on your visualisation of these 2D features, $x_1$ and $x_2$, on the training set, you noticed that using cubic polynomial features should allow a better model performance. Write down all the polynomial features in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

I find this problem wording confusing. If there are cubic polynomial features, then isn't this a polynomial regression, not a linear regression? My understanding is that, if we have the cubic polynomial features $x_1$ and $x_2$, then the polynomial regression would be $ \hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1^2 + \beta_4 x_1 x_2 + \beta_5 x_2^2 + \beta_6 x_1^3 + \beta_7 x_1^2 x_2 + \beta_8 x_1 x_2^2 + \beta_9 x_2^3$, right? But don't the interaction terms make this nonlinear, rather than linear (regression)? Am I misunderstanding something here?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+linear+nonlinear+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10

@whuber That question and its answers do not address the interaction terms aspect. I think there is value in having this specific question answered.

On the contrary, I believe that aspect is fully addressed.  What do you believe might be lacking?

@whuber I did a search for "interaction" and found nothing for that question or its answers. I think it's unreasonable to the point of silliness to just close anything that is significantly related to something else and link it all to that one question. As long as the questions aren't so similar that nothing significant is added by the new question, I think there's obviously value in addressing a concept from multiple, diverse angles.

Polynomial regression is a name typically used for a linear model with polynomial terms ($x^2$, $x^3$). However, since you can still express the relationship in terms of intercept and slope(s), it is still a linear model and can be fit with OLS. The interaction terms do not change this, because they are still multiplied by their own $\beta$.

@FransRodenburg Oh, ok. So there's nothing wrong with my understanding of $\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1^2 + \beta_4 x_1 x_2 + \beta_5 x_2^2 + \beta_6 x_1^3 + \beta_7 x_1^2 x_2 + \beta_8 x_1 x_2^2 + \beta_9 x_2^3$ as being the correct equation?

Think about it this way: I can precompute all the terms in your model and call them $z_j$. For example, $z_4 = x_1 \cdot x_2$. I can then run a multiple linear regression $\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^9 \beta_j z_j$.

Your interpretation is fine!

@FransRodenburg Yes, that makes sense. Linear regression means linear in terms of the $\beta_i$, not the $x_i$.
